# How to plot feature map comprised of tfidf and polarity using pyplot?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, plot, data-visualization, svm

I have around 322 text documents. I generated tfidf vector for those documents. I also have polarity assigned to each document(which is a float number). Then I have keywords as columns, and have marked them as 1 if they are present in the documents.

The data is divided into True or False

Considering all this, I have 5300 columns for each documents. Now to decide, which SVM to use, I want to know how can I write the code for plotting the feature map so I can see the structure of data.